# Noun for "act of striving"

Tags: nouns

Is there a noun for the *act of striving*?

Many English verbs use the same word for the infinitive (e.g. *to fall*) and for the *act of performing that action* (e.g. *a fall*), but I haven't found whether *strive* can be used as the *act of striving*. Is there a synonym that could work?

Comment: You're confusing action and event. _A fall_ is a punctual non-volitional event involving the action of falling; _strive_, on the other hand, is a durative volitional verb, and thus does not form punctual event nominalizations. There are a lot more different kinds of verbs than one might imagine.

Comment: In this case, just use the gerund - [his **striving** was in vain](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22his+striving+was+in+vain%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) simply means *his act[s] of striving achieved nothing*.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't see how I confused action with event. I didn't say _a fall_ is an action I said it's an act, the act of falling, being _a fall_ the act and _falling_ the action. I understand though what you mean about _punctual and non-volitional_ vs. _durative and volitional_. So this noun forms only come with punctual verbs and not with durative ones? What about one of the examples given in an answer (_to endeavour_, _an endeavour_)? Should we consider it a punctual verb (i.e. making a punctual effort)? Disclaimer: I really don't mean to create discord, I just want to understand it well.

Comment: _Act_ has a specific meaning in semantics. It requires a volitional subject, usually human; i.e, it's on purpose. _Falling_ is not an act; it's a (usually temporary) state. _Events_ include acts, but not the other way around; _events_ are any occurrence in time, volitional or accidental. And I don't understand what you mean by "this noun forms", so I can't comment on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider *[endeavor](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/endeavour?view=uk)*

> [mass noun] earnest, prolonged, and industrious effort:
>   enthusiasm is a vital ingredient in all human endeavour

Answer (score 0):

As John Lawler points out in his comment, verbs like [*strive*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/strive) and *seek* are  different in character from verbs like *find* and *yeild*, albeit arguably somewhat subtly.

That said, you might try [*an attempt*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/attempt) if you want one singular punctuated act, but that isn't quite the same as *striving*, which is a more continuous thing.

---

> *We are not now that strength which in old days
>
>   Moved earth and heaven; that which we are, we are;
>
>   One equal temper of heroic hearts,
>
>   Made weak by time and fate, but strong in will
>
>   To strive, to seek, to find, and not to yield.*

Answer (score 0):

I like the term ***industry***

M-w.com offers the following definitions:

> 1. : diligence in an employment or pursuit; especially : steady or habitual effort
>
> 2a : systematic labor especially for some useful purpose or the
>   creation of something of value

Answer (score -3):

I would say *strife* is another option.

Comment: But *strife* sounds more like a conflict of some sort.

Comment: In Shakespearian times, you would have been right.  That meaning is now archaic and not in current use.  I would say that "strife" describes a state (that is, a condition), not an act.  Also, "strife" has a negative connotation in modern usage, where "strive" generally has a positive one.